# How to rebuild a parent widget from a child widget from a user action?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

Every time the user adds a different product to their shopping cart, the amount shown in the navbar icon must be updated.
[image]

to add the product to the shopping cart we do it from another widget by pressing the button
[image]

the navigation bar is a separate widget. I don't know how to update the quantity shown in the shopping cart icon when adding the product to the shopping cart.

I am using a streambuilder to achieve this but I have to rebuild the navbar widget so that the amount is just updated. Anyone have any idea how this reconstruction is done asynchronously or in the background. Im junior programmer in flutter :)

NAVBAR WIDGET

```
    class Navbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavbarState createState() => _NavbarState();
}

class _NavbarState extends State<Navbar> {

   final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      Home(),
      Carrito(),
      TrackingPurchase(),
      ComprobantePage(),
      Profile(),
   ];

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  int productInCar = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: iconColor,
        backgroundColor: primaryColor,
        items:  <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
            title: Text(
              'Productos',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'ComfortaaLight',
                fontSize: 12
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                Container(
                  height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
                  width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                    color: primaryColor,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: StreamBuilder<int>(
                      stream: StreamCarritoCount().shoppingCartController.stream,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return Text(
                          snapshot.data.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: secondaryColor,
                              fontSize: 10
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Carrito',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ComfortaaMedium',
                  fontSize: 12
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.place),
            title: Text(
              'Tracking',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ComfortaaMedium',
                  fontSize: 12
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.insert_drive_file),
            title: Text(
              'Documentos',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ComfortaaMedium',
                  fontSize: 12
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text(
              'Perfil',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'ComfortaaMedium',
                  fontSize: 12
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: primaryColor,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

HOME WIDGET

```
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<String> marcas = ['Colageno','Slim'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return  SingleChildScrollView(
          child: BlocProvider(
            create: (BuildContext context) => sl<ProductsHomeBloc>()..add(GetListProducstEvent()),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
                right: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
              ),
              height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 100,
              width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                  ),
                  HeaderHome(),
                  Divider(
                    color: grayPrex,
                  ),
                  // MARCAS LIST
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
                        bottom: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3
                    ),
                    height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5,
                    width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                          children: List<Widget>.generate(marcas.length, (index) {
                            return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5
                              ),
                              child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        right: 20
                                    ),
                                    child: Text(
                                      marcas[index],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'ComfortaaMedium',
                                        fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                        color: subTitle,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          )
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // LIST TOP PRODUCTS
                  Container(
                      height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 36,
                      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 25
                      ),
                      child: BlocBuilder<ProductsHomeBloc, ProductsHomeState>(
                          builder: (context,state) {
                            if (state is EmptyListProductsState) {
                              return Container(
                                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                              );
                            } else if (state is LoadingListProductsState) {
                              return PreloadScreen(
                                  textColor: textColor,
                                  iconProgressColor: primaryColor,
                                  backColor: background,
                                  message: 'Cargando producto'
                              );
                            } else if (state is LoadedListProductsState) {
                              //_executeGetIdentifier(context);
                              final productsEntities = state.listProduct.toList();
                              return ListView(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                children: List<Widget>.generate(state.listProduct.length, (index) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: CardTopProduct(
                                      idProduct: productsEntities[index].idProduct,
                                      name: productsEntities[index].name,
                                      precio: productsEntities[index].unitPrice,
                                      imgProduct: productsEntities[index].imgProduct,
                                    ),
                                  );

                                }),
                              );
                            }
                            return null;
                          }
                      )
                  ),
                  // PRODUCTOS MAS VENDIDOS
                  Container(
                    height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                    width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Mas vendidos',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'ComfortaaBold',
                        fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 4,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: textColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // LIST PRODUCTS
                  Container(
                    height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 32,
                    child: BlocBuilder<ProductsHomeBloc, ProductsHomeState>(
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          if (state is EmptyListProductsState) {
                            return Container(
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            );
                          } else if (state is LoadingListProductsState) {
                            return PreloadScreen(
                                textColor: textColor,
                                iconProgressColor: primaryColor,
                                backColor: background,
                                message: 'Cargando producto'
                            );
                          } else if (state is LoadedListProductsState) {
                            final productsEntities = state.listProduct.toList();
                            return GridView.count(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                              children: List<Widget>.generate(productsEntities.length, (index) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                  child: FittedBox(child: CardProductHome(
                                    idProduct: productsEntities[index].idProduct,
                                    name: productsEntities[index].name,
                                    price: productsEntities[index].unitPrice,
                                    imgProduct: productsEntities[index].imgProduct,
                                  )
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                            );
                          }
                          return Container();
                        }
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
       
  }
}
```

CARD PRODUCT

```
class CardProductHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final int idProduct;
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final String imgProduct;

  CardProductHome({
    Key key,
    @required this.idProduct,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.imgProduct,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DetailsProduct(idProducto: idProduct)
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 4,
            right: 4
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: background,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: shadowDarkSignUp,
                offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                blurRadius: 5,
              ),
              BoxShadow(
                color: shadowClearSignUp,
                offset: Offset(-5.0, -5.0),
                blurRadius: 5.0,
              ),
            ]
        ),
        height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 25,
        width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 40,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.indigo[700],
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2,
                      ),
                      height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 12,
                      width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5,
                      child: RotatedBox(
                        quarterTurns: 3,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Nuevo',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: 'ComfortaaBold',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 3
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_border,
                        color: textColor,
                        size: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2.5,
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 15,
                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 1
                  ),
                  child: Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        imgProduct
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2.5,
            ),
            Container(
              width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 55,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 2,
                      fontFamily: 'ComfortaaBold',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      color: titleColor
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2,
            ),
            Text(
              price.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 2,
                  color: titleColor,
                  fontFamily: 'ComfortaaMedium'
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

DETAILS_PRODUCT WIDGET

```
GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () => _AddProductToCarrito(context),
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5,
                                  top: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 1
                              ),
                              height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 7,
                              width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 91,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2),
                                color: primaryColor,
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.shopping_basket,
                                      color: secondaryColor,
                                      size: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 8,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Agregar al Carrito',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                        color: secondaryColor,
                                        fontFamily: 'ComfortaaLight',
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: You want update count when tap in button?

Comment: yes i wish to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new ParentWidgetState();
}

class ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int _cardCount = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    // ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: Stack(
         children: [ 
           ChildWidget(onTapButton: () {
             setState(() {
              _cardCount = _cardCount + 1;
              });
           }
     ]));
  }
}


class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onTapButton;

  ChildWidget({this.onTapButton}));

  @override
  createState() => new ChildWidgetState();
}

class ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    // ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: Stack(
         children: [ 
          YourButton(
            onTap: () {
              widget.onTapButton();
              })
     ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have three widgets: navigation bar widget, home widget(where are products), and product details widget; in this last widget is the Add button and the shopping cart icon is in the navigation bar widget. the parent of the details_product widget is home widget.

Comment: ``onTapButton`` call in home widget and increase count and from home screen this count send to ``navigationBar`` widget.

Comment: if you can't do this, share your code I add missing code

Comment: I just edited my question, there I shared the code